# Executing a sql function multiple times takes too much time

Tags: sql-server

I have created a udf, when running this function multiple times like this :

```
select 
dbo.ufngetpercentagematch('http://www.booking.com/hotel/au/crowne-plaza-melbourne.en-gb.html','CROWNE PLAZA MELBOURNE'),
dbo.ufngetpercentagematch('http://www.hotelclub.com/hotels/Australia--VI/Melbourne/Crowne_Plaza_MELBOURNE.h175114/','CROWNE PLAZA MELBOURNE'),
dbo.ufngetpercentagematch('http://www.orbitz.com/hotel/Australia--VI/Melbourne/Crowne_Plaza_MELBOURNE.h175114/','CROWNE PLAZA MELBOURNE'),
dbo.ufngetpercentagematch('http://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g255100-d255387-Reviews-Crowne_Plaza_Melbourne-Melbourne_Victoria.html','CROWNE PLAZA MELBOURNE')
```

it takes 7 sec.
Whereas running each of the select statement individually takes almost 10-15 micro secs each.
Can someone tell why this is happening?

Might there be something wrong with function or some function property that I am missing?

Table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[NoiseWords](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Word] [nvarchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [Deleted] [bit] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_NoiseWords] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[NoiseWords] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Deleted]
GO


insert into noisewords(word) values('The')
insert into noisewords(word) values('A')
insert into noisewords(word) values('Hotel')
insert into noisewords(word) values('villa')
insert into noisewords(word) values('villas')
insert into noisewords(word) values('resort')
insert into noisewords(word) values('$')
insert into noisewords(word) values('an')
insert into noisewords(word) values('and')
insert into noisewords(word) values('resorts')
insert into noisewords(word) values('home')
insert into noisewords(word) values('house')
insert into noisewords(word) values('homes')
insert into noisewords(word) values('houses')
insert into noisewords(word) values('cottage')
insert into noisewords(word) values('cottages')
insert into noisewords(word) values('hotels')
insert into noisewords(word) values('inn')
insert into noisewords(word) values('inns')
insert into noisewords(word) values('hoteles')
insert into noisewords(word) values('guest')
insert into noisewords(word) values('hostel')
insert into noisewords(word) values('hostels')
insert into noisewords(word) values('room')
insert into noisewords(word) values('rooms')
insert into noisewords(word) values('apartment')
insert into noisewords(word) values('apartments')
insert into noisewords(word) values('housing')
insert into noisewords(word) values('lodging')
insert into noisewords(word) values('motel')
insert into noisewords(word) values('motels')
insert into noisewords(word) values('roof')
insert into noisewords(word) values('shelter')
insert into noisewords(word) values('spa')
insert into noisewords(word) values('spas')
insert into noisewords(word) values('tavern')
insert into noisewords(word) values('taverns')
insert into noisewords(word) values('saloon')
insert into noisewords(word) values('dormitory')
insert into noisewords(word) values('camp')
insert into noisewords(word) values('camps')
insert into noisewords(word) values('cabin')
insert into noisewords(word) values('cabins')
insert into noisewords(word) values('suites')
insert into noisewords(word) values('suite')
```

ufnGetPercentageMatch

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ufnGetPercentageMatch    
(@reference nvarchar(1000),    
@input nvarchar(1000))    
RETURNS  decimal(6,2)    
AS    
begin    

 --declare @reference nvarchar(1000)='764 4th Ave'    
 --declare @input nvarchar(1000)='764 4th Ave, Brooklyn, NY, 11232, USA'    

 set @input = ' '+ ltrim(rtrim(dbo.ufnRemoveNonAlphaNumericCharacters(dbo.ufnReplaceAccentChars(replace(replace(' ' + @input + ' ',' BW ',' '),' Best Western ',' ')))))+' '    
 set @reference = ' '+ ltrim(rtrim(dbo.ufnRemoveNonAlphaNumericCharacters(dbo.ufnReplaceAccentChars(replace(replace(' ' + @reference + ' ' ,' BW ',' '),' Best Western ',' ')))))+' '    
 --print @input     
 --print @reference    
 declare @max int    
 declare @counter int =1    
 select @max = count(1) from noisewords    
 declare @query1 varchar(max)=''    
 declare @query2 nvarchar(max)=''    
 declare @noiseword varchar(500)=''    
 declare @percmatch decimal(6,2)=0    
 while @max >= @counter    
 begin    
  select @noiseword=' ' + ltrim(rtrim(word)) + ' ' from noisewords where id = @counter and deleted = 0    
  set @input = replace(@input,@noiseword,' ')    
  set @reference = replace(@reference,@noiseword,' ')    
  set @counter = @counter + 1    
 end    

 --print @reference + '::' + @input    

 declare @query nvarchar(max)    
 set @query= 'select ' + @query1 + '''' +  @input + '''' + @query2    

 ;with cte1 as    
 (    
  select *     
  from     
  splitstring(@input,' ')    
 ),    
 cte2 as    
 (    
  select item,@reference as ref, case when @reference like '%'+item+'%' then 1 else 0 end as c    
  from cte1    
  where isnull(item,'')<>''    
 ),    
 cte3 as    
 (    
  select @input as inp,@reference as ref,sum(c) as sum,count(1) as total,    
   cast(sum(c)  as decimal(6,2))/(cast(count(1) as decimal(6,2))) as avg    
  from cte2    
 )    
 select @percmatch = isnull(avg,0) from cte3    
 --select * from cte2    
 --print @percmatch    
 RETURN(@percmatch)    
END
```

ufnRemoveNonAlphaNumericCharacters

```
Create Function [dbo].[ufnRemoveNonAlphaNumericCharacters](@Temp VarChar(1000))  
Returns VarChar(1000)  
AS  
Begin  

    Declare @KeepValues as varchar(50)  
    Set @KeepValues = '%[^a-z0-9 ]%'  
    While PatIndex(@KeepValues, @Temp) > 0  
        Set @Temp = Stuff(@Temp, PatIndex(@KeepValues, @Temp), 1, '')  

    Return @Temp  
End
```

ufnReplaceAccentChars

```
create function [dbo].[ufnReplaceAccentChars] ( @p_OriginalString varchar(max) )  
returns varchar(max) as  
begin  
  declare @ModifiedString varchar(100) = @p_OriginalString Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AI;  
  return @ModifiedString  
end
```

SplitString

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitString]  
(      
      @Input VARCHAR(8000),  
      @Character CHAR(1)  
)  
RETURNS @Output TABLE (  
      Item VARCHAR(1000)  
)  
AS  
BEGIN  
      DECLARE @StartIndex INT, @EndIndex INT  

      SET @StartIndex = 1  
      IF SUBSTRING(@Input, LEN(@Input) - 1, LEN(@Input)) <> @Character  
      BEGIN  
            SET @Input = @Input + @Character  
      END  

      WHILE CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input) > 0  
      BEGIN  
            SET @EndIndex = CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input)  

            INSERT INTO @Output(Item)  
            SELECT SUBSTRING(@Input, @StartIndex, @EndIndex - 1)  

            SET @Input = SUBSTRING(@Input, @EndIndex + 1, LEN(@Input))  
      END  

      RETURN  
END
```

Comment: The performance problem is because scalar functions like this are horrible for performance. And when you call a scalar udf for every column it is going to degrade very quickly. Perhaps you can convert this function to an inline table valued function instead? Just make sure if you do the table valued function that it is one and only one statement or you aren't going to gain any performance.

Comment: Also, youve not told us what `ufngetpercentagematch` *does*!

Comment: @Jamiec **ufngetpercentagematch** gets the percentage match between the first and second input i.e. how many of the second input words are there in the first input.
Is there any other way I can do this in sql?

Comment: @GunmeetSingh we can help but you need to post the code for that function. Without those details there is nothing we can do to help. Here is an excellent article to help you get started. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @SeanLange I have posted the function and tables. Thanks for the help, I am new to this ;)

Comment: Excellent job posting details!!! There is so much room for improvement here it is hard to know where to start. There is at least one more function "split" that we can't see. There are loops nested with loops nested with loops. This whole process needs a complete rewrite. The problem is that sql is a declarative language and does NOT work well with looping. In addition to all the looping there are nonSARGable predicates. For example isnull(item,'')<>''  forces an index scan no matter what you do. This is as simple as item > '' to correct it.

Comment: @SeanLange Included the SplitString function.
I know looping should not be there in sql, but I can't think of a logic to get rid of them. Can you help with the logic? I will look into nonSARGable predicates and remove them.
But after changing this also, it still will remain a scalar function..Any way improve upon that?

Comment: Converting this into an inline table valued function is way beyond the scope of a forum post. For the splitter you need to trash that loop based one and get a faster set based version. My favorite can be found here. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/. For some other good examples see here. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: Your two other scalar functions should be converted to inline table valued functions. Then your main function needs to be converted. It a somewhat big piece of work, especially when it is new to you, but you will be rewarded with a massive learning experience and super fast code when you are done.

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks for all the help..I will work on the functions and try changing them to inline functions..I went through the links and they are great !!! 
One more thing, can changing them to CLR functions also give the same benefits?

Comment: CLR comes with some fairly heavy baggage. It might be faster for heavy string manipulation but it seems like overkill for what you are doing here.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer as that would be a bit more than a forum can provide but here is an example of converting your scalar function ufnReplaceAccentChars to an inline table valued function. One logical problem I see with the old function is that it receives a varchar(max) and truncates it to 100 characters.

```
create function [dbo].[ufnReplaceAccentChars] 
( 
    @p_OriginalString varchar(max) 
)  
returns table as
    return select left(@p_OriginalString, 100) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AI as ReplacedValue;
```

If you follow either of the links I provided earlier you can find some excellent replacements for your split function. The remove special characters is a bit more tricky. Then you still have the main query and that removal of noise words to deal with. Hopefully this will get you started.